# Setting up simple POST response in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a simple POST request via jquery's .ajax function to a routed URL in rails, but can't get a simple response.

Is there any way of setting up a simple response in rails without using any of the AJAX helper functions? In PHP, you can just echo a simple response out, but rails seems to want to wrap everything in HTML.

Comment: Did you try specifying :method => :post in the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple response (I guess you need just to output some text) you can use

```
render :text => "Whatever you need to response" #in your controller
```

Comment: `render plain: "Whatever you need to response"`

This is the new replacement for `render :text =>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify that you dont want to render the layout if request.xhr?.

In controller

```
layout :layout_for_type

def layout_for_type
   request.xhr? ? nil : "application"
end
```